# javascript: lightweight lightbox script

Tags: javascript

i'm looking for a lightweight javascript for displaying images the way lightbox does.
it should be small + simple, no jquery/mootools plugin, no animations.

i just should be able to display an image when clicking on its thumbnail.

thanks

Comment: 'small and simple' and not using a js library don't go together; one of the joys of a js library is not having to handle the myriad of browser inconsistencies. Unless you meant "simple to use" as opposed to "simple code".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for example [Lytebox](http://www.dolem.com/lytebox/). This script doesn't have any dependencies on external libraries and integrating it with your page is as easy as using Lightbox

Comment: Lytebox does its job without requiring an external library, but it's not exactly "light" (95.2kb JS + 13.2kb CSS).

Comment: **[jsOnlyLightbox](http://jslightbox.felixhagspiel.de/)** JS only, no jQuery  or other library needed, responsive and IE8 support. and less than 20KB if you leave out the animation GIF (JS only is 8KB)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something *really* light-weight, you might take a look at [this script](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/minibox.js).

To convert all links whose URLs end in `.jpg`, `.png` or `.gif`, add the following lines to the bottom of your page:

```
<script src="minibox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
minibox.borderSize = 5;
minibox.borderType = 'solid red';
minibox.img.title = 'click to close image window';
minibox();
</script>
```

There is no documentation, but the code is reasonably clear.